# Loading data from Joomla using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla

I am currently coding a timetable application with PHP.

What I want to do is to have a button for each day of the week and that when a user clicks each button, the tasks listed down for that day are loaded into the browser window using JavaScript.

My current code is:

```
<?php
class loadTimetable
{
    public static function getTimetable( $params )
    {
        //Obtain a database connection
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        //Retrieve the shout
        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                    ->select($db->quoteName('title'))
                    ->from($db->quoteName('#__timetable'))
                    ->where('day = '. $db->Quote($params));
        //Prepare the query
        $db->setQuery($query);
        // Load the row.
        $result = $db->loadResult();
        //Return the Hello
        return $result;
    }
}
$day = date("N");
$timetable = getTimetable($day);
?>
<h1><?php echo $timetable; ?></h1>
```

The function is inside Joomla and has been tested to work fine. The help I need is how to call that function using Javascript/AJAX.

As far as I can see, all Javascript would have to do is call the function with the selected day (e.g, `getTimetable(1)` where 1 is the value for the Monday button in the HTML).

Comment: You are using Joomla, yet don't seem to use any of its guidelines or practices. Are you creating a component? Are you just using the Joomla platform/framework? Have you read the docs?

Comment: Hi @MasterAM I am creating a module to compliment a component. The above code is split between the module PHP file, a helper PHP file and a template PHP file as per the Joomla framework. I just consolidated all the code so non-Joomla programmers could help out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question and further comments, you should move your code (or its invocation at least) to the component. Only components can be "invoked".  There are many options, but to keep it simple you need at least (in the component):

1. A task in a controller, i.e. a function `getTimetable()` that will receive the ajax call;
   This can also be done in a subcontroller.  In case of a controller, you will invoke it with `index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&task=getTimetable&day=2011-09-17`, in case of a subcontroller `task=subcontroller.getTimetable`
2. The function you pasted in a module, let's call it timemodule for now, and `getTimetable($day)` will need to be public.
3. The `controller:getTimetable()` function will

   3.a. parse and sanitize the day parameter input;

   3.b. instantiate the module timemodule

   3.c. instantiate the view, inject the module, let it load the results from db and

   3.d. invoke the view's `render()` method

   3.e. the `exit` statement (so Joomla will not render the template and other modules (all you want is the json/xml output).

There are, of course, many alternatives; in the controller you may set a day variable using `setUserState`, then redirect to the view, and use the variable from userstate in the module; it's really a matter of preference, what you want to keep in mind is that the `exit` statement should be invoked in the loop that renders output, so if you redirect you'll invoke it in the view's `display()` method.  You may also append `&format=json` to your url to achieve this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my programming knowledge is way below the level of what you described above! Currently I have 
`for($x=1;$x<8;$x++)
    {
        $days[$x] = getTimetable($x);
    }`
This loads all the day data into an array.
`<div><?php echo $days[1]; ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $days[2]; ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $days[3]; ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $days[4]; ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $days[5]; ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $days[6]; ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $days[7]; ?></div>`
To load the data on the page. This works so far, but it is not dynamic. That's what I need help with. :)

Comment: The question was about invoking from Joomla, you might want to open a new one for this issue (or at least use a foreach loop in the view!)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Riccardo-Zorn. I did find a workaround in JavaScript but am not knowledgeable enough in either PHP or AJAX yet to code it the way you answered. Accepted it so you get the points though, it sounds correct. :)